# Azure portal error when changing website web hosting plan

Tags: azure, portal

I have three Azure websites. All of them are in the "West Europe" Azure region and all are "Shared" scaling. One of the sites require a custom domain and SSL certificate, so the decision was made to scale the website to "Standard".

My understanding (after reading [this blog post](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/PennyPinchingInTheCloudWhenDoAzureWebsitesMakeSense.aspx))is: A "Standard" web hosting plan is created and the site is moved to the new web hosting plan. A "Standard" web hosting plan, also allows me to have multiple sites using the same web hosting plan (i.e. the total cost of the "Standard" web host plan stays fixed regardless of the number of sites in that web hosting plan).

When I log into the "new" portal. My websites are now as follows:

Website A - West Europe - Shared - Hosting plan Default 1
Website B - West Europe - Shared - Hosting plan Default 1
Website C - West Europe - Standard - Hosting plan Default 2

I want to move websites A and B to the new Default 2 web hosting plan. I go to the specific website, click the three dots and click "Change Web Hosting Plan". I select the "Default 2 - Standard" web hosting plan.

Then all the tiles on the portal disappear, and the notification icon turns violet. When I click on the violet notifications icon, the following error notification is listed:

```
Failed to update website web hosting plan.
Failed to update website A to web hosting plan Default2. The request content was invalid and could not be deserialized: 'Error converting value "{
    "SubscriptionId": "db2a05ba-c00c-47d6-a583-3fe0e266*****",
    "ResourceGroup": "Default-Web-WestEurope",
    "Location": "West Europe",
    "Properties": {
        "Name": "A",
        "State": null,
        "HostNames": null,
        "WebSpace": null,
        "SelfLink": null,
        "RepositorySiteName": null,
        "Owner": null,
        "UsageState": 0,
        "Enabled": null,
        "AdminEnabled": null,
        "EnabledHostNames": null,
        "SiteProperties": null,
        "AvailabilityState": 0,
        "SSLCertificates": null,
        "Csrs": null,
        "Cers": null,
        "SiteMode": null,
        "HostNameSslStates": null,
        "ComputeMode": null,
        "ServerFarm": "Default3",
        "WebHostingPlan": null,
        "LastModifiedTimeUtc": "0001-01-01T00:00:00",
        "StorageRecoveryDefaultState": null,
        "ContentAvailabilityState": 0,
        "RuntimeAvailabilityState": 0,
        "SiteConfig": null,
        "DeploymentId": null,
        "TrafficManagerHostNames": null,
        "SKU": null,
        "PremiumAppDeployed": null,
        "ScmSiteAlsoStopped": null
    }
}" to type 'Microsoft.WindowsAzure.ResourceStack.Frontdoor.Data.Definitions.ResourceDefinition'. Path '', line 1, position 879.'.
```

Am I doing something wrong?

UPDATE: All sites are in the same resource group: "Default-Web-WestEurope"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, as George said you are doing everything correct. I have contacted Microsoft Azure Support and gave them a screen shot of the error that I am getting. I will keep you updated as I hear back from MS Support (hopefully with a fix to the issue).

UPDATE: 
So guys... still waiting to hear back from MS Support(as usual). I have found a fix using Microsoft Azure PowerShell.

You will want to download MS Azure PowerShell.
Once you have launched the program type what I have below:

- `Switch-AzureMode AzureResourceManager` <kbd>Enter</kbd>
- `Add-AzureAccount` (you will be prompted to sign in) <kbd>Enter</kbd>
- `$r = Get-AzureResource -Name siteNameGoesHere` <kbd>Enter</kbd>
- `ResourceGroupName: nameofResourceGroup` <kbd>Enter</kbd>
- `ResourceType: Microsoft.Web/sites` <kbd>Enter</kbd>
- `ApiVersion: 2014-04-01` <kbd>Enter</kbd>
- `$p = $null;` <kbd>Enter</kbd>
- `$p = @{'ServerFarm' = 'nameOfHostingPlan'}` <kbd>Enter</kbd>(You must leave 'ServerFarm' but 'nameOfHostingPlan' is the plan you want to move the website to)
- `$r = Set-AzureResource -Name nameofSite -ResourceGroupName nameofResource          -ResourceType Microsoft.Web/sites -ApiVersion 2014-04-01 -PropertyObject $p` <kbd>Enter</kbd>

Then you should return to the Azure Portal and hit refresh. I have done it twice today, it is somewhat tedious but a fix until MS fixes the button within the portal.

Please let me know if you all need any help!

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! This came to me for review as a first answer - usually you might want to consider moving it to a comment, but in this case (as you suggest you will in the text) I think it stands as an answer if you edit the answer once you have more information.

Comment: That seems to be the interim solution. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You are doing everything correctly.

I have successfully done this numerous times in the past. However, I logged on today to move another website from the Free tier to the Shared tier and got the exact error you did.

This leads me to believe there may be an issue with Azure (as there have been many recently).

I would check again every few hours/days.

Answer (score 0):

This appears to still be an occurrence in the azure portal (https://portal.azure.com).  I have had success converting to a Standard plan in the past by going to the classic portal (https://manage.windowsazure.com) and converting the plan there.